# Using golang server to serve flutterweb app and rest api at the same time

Tags: go, flutter-web

I have a flutter mobile app which consumes services from a golang server via rest api. It works fine in all aspects. I ported the app to a web project and created a golang server to serve its files. Also works correctly.
This is the golang http server code, copied from another question from SO.

```
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func main() {
    port := flag.String("p", "8181", "port to serve on")
    directory := flag.String("d", "web", "the directory of static file to host")
    flag.Parse()
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(*directory)))
    log.Printf("Serving %s on HTTP port: %s\n", *directory, *port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+*port, nil))
}
```

This is (part of) the code of the rest api server:

```
func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    http.Handle("/", r)

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bdlocation.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    BdLocation = string(content)

    r.HandleFunc("/api/getmenu", get_menu).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/getmenuitems", get_menu_items).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/image/{file}", WebHandler).Methods("GET")
    ... etc... 
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

The current status of my problem is:

1. the web server works correctly in terms of interface, navigation, etc., exactly like the mobile app.
2. the rest server works correctly when consumed from the mobile app.
3. can't make the two communicate. My goal is to call the flutter web app in a browser and from there to use the rest api.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. run both servers on the same machine each having its own port. I called localhost:8181 (web app) from the browser, and from this environment I called http:8000/api/xxxx to get the rest data. Did not work
2. tried to "merge" the two servers into something like this:

```
func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    http.Handle("/", r)

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bdlocation.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    BdLocation = string(content)

    directory := flag.String("d", "web", "the directory of static file to host")
    flag.Parse()
    // if the call is http:localhost, serve the web app...
    r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(*directory)))
    // if it is somethins else serve the corresponding api function
    r.HandleFunc("/api/getmenu", get_menu).Methods("GET")
    ... etc...    
    r.HandleFunc("/api/image/{file}", WebHandler).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

did not work either, although it compiled correctly.

I also have to say that I don't get any error messages when I try these approaches, and I am not an expert on debugging web apps, so I am not able to provide more clues as to what might be going wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need more visibility on what is happening to the requests so you can answer questions like "is the request received by the server?" That one could be answered by putting some logs into your server code. How do you send your requests? You could use POSTMAN or similar to compose them, or curl if you're comfortable with that, but either way you need to inspect the response to find out if the problem is that the request never reaches the server, or something else.

Comment: I will post another question. Using your suggestions I figured out what the problem was but it would be very complicated to explain it here. Thanks!